# Remove dynamic token from SAPUI5 app path when loading from SAP BTP cockpit

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cloud-foundry, sap-cloud-connector

I have created sapui5 app and deployed it to cloud but when I am accessing it from SAP BTP cockpit I am getting dynamic token in the path which will create issue when I deploy it to other system because I am using this app as component container in other apps.
Can someone tell me how to remove this.
Screenshot attached below.

Dynamic Number befor app name in path [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iyzj3.png)

I tried creating app with different approach but still getting it.